# Find last occurrence of an entry in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like so:

```
     Id | Modified | OwnerId| Mode
    ----+----------+---------+-----
     1  | 14/01/14 |    101  | On  
     2  | 14/02/21 |    102  | Off 
     3  | 14/03/21 |    102  | On 
     4  | 14/04/21 |    102  | Off
     5  | 14/05/21 |    102  | On  
     6  | 14/05/22 |    105  | Off
     7  | 14/06/21 |    102  | Off
```

I want to find the last occurence of each OwnerId where Mode equals 'Off' like so:

```
     Id | Modified | OwnerId| Mode
    ----+----------+---------+-----
     6  | 14/05/22 |    105  | Off
     7  | 14/06/21 |    102  | Off
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sth like this should work:

```
SELECT Id, Modified, OwnerId, Mode
FROM (
   SELECT Id, Modified, OwnerId, Mode,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OwnerId ORDER BY Modified DESC) As rn
   FROM MyTable
   Where Mode = 'Off'
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

Comment: Wow, I've searched for hours for a solution to this problem and seen alot of variations that didn't really cut it, but the above query is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.